# Print "₹" in Magento 1.9.3 Invoice using System font

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to make my invoice smaller in size. Right now, I am using DejaVu font to print my invoice since that supports printing of "₹" symbol on my invoices. However, it increases the size of invoice as it gets embedded in invoice file. (See [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4816/33631) )

I tried using `Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES_ROMAN` in place of DejaVu. It indeed make my file smaller (from 1145 KB to 14 KB), but my symbol is not printed.

How can I make my file smaller in size while printing "₹" in invoices?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In CSS

```
.rupee {
    background-position:left;
    width: 10px;
    height: 14px;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJZ9m.png');
    display:block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

In HTML

```
<span class="rupee"></span>
Rupee Symbol in html:- <span>&#8377;</span>
<br>
Rupee :- <span>&#8360;</span>
```

Source from http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fZpXM/

Hope it will help you.

Comment: My question is regarding invoice sir, not frontend.