# How to make invoice PDF file size compress in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.2.5, invoice-pdf

I'm trying to make compress invoice PDF file size. How to make this in Magento 2.2.5. Default PDF size is 3.2MB

I'm trying to make this in between 19KB. How to make this?

I tried below link's solution but my PDF reduce to 800kb. Not able to do make it 19kb. Here is the link I tried.

[Reduce PDF file size in magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4812/why-is-my-invoice-pdf-1mb)

How to add custom font also? There is two type of font I found in Magento 2.2.5 setup. But no hope by them.

Please help anybody. I tried lot, but unable to do this.

Comment: Change the font sizes as well. Also are you working with product images in your pdf? http://www.magpleasure.com/blog/change-fonts-and-reduce-file-size-for-pdf-invoice-in-magento.html

Comment: Default font was **GnuFreeFont**, I changed it to **LinLibertineFont**. But still no hope and it became 800kb but not 19kb, and I saw the link before you share. How to embed this font **FONT_HELVETICA**.  When I include the line, the section giving error. **And I'm trying to make this changes in Magento 2.2.5**

Comment: No need to include the Helvetica has its already available. You can directly add it. But according to the blog you are following is for magento 1 not for magento 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to consolidate all this information:

1: Create (or use) a custom module under `app/code/YourModule` - eg `app/code/YourModule/Sales`

2: Add a `<preference \>` entry to `app/code/YourModule/Sales/etc/di.xml` - eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <!-- ... -->

    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="YourModule\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />

</config>
```

3: Create the file `app/code/YourModule/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php`

```
<?php
namespace YourModule\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf;

/**
 * Use built-in fonts in PDFs so that invoices are smaller.
 *
 */
class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{
    protected function _setFontRegular($object, $size = 7)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA); // or FONT_TIMES for serif
        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }

    protected function _setFontBold($object, $size = 7)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA_BOLD); // or FONT_TIMES_BOLD for serif
        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }

    protected function _setFontItalic($object, $size = 7)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA_ITALIC); // or FONT_TIMES_ITALIC for serif
        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }
}
```

That will reduce your invoices from 3Mb each to 2Kb.

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace below functions:

```
protected function _setFontRegular($object, $size = 7)
{
    /*$font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
        $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/LinLibertineFont/LinLibertine_Re-4.4.1.ttf')
    );*/
    $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
    $object->setFont($font, $size);
    return $font;
}
```

and

```
protected function _setFontBold($object, $size = 7)
{
    /*$font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
        $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/LinLibertineFont/LinLibertine_Bd-2.8.1.ttf')
    );*/
    $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
    $object->setFont($font, $size);
    return $font;
}
```

and

```
protected function _setFontItalic($object, $size = 7)
{
    /*$font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
        $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/LinLibertineFont/LinLibertine_It-2.8.2.ttf')
    );*/
    $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
    $object->setFont($font, $size);
    return $font;
}
```

You can see that I have replaced the default font to HELVETICA and its works fine for me.